# React passing parent function to grandchild via context

Tags: reactjs

Does anyone have or know of a full example of passing a function via React context from a parent to a grandchild and then executing the function from the grandchild? I found a butt load of examples of strings and bools, but failed to locate one for a function.

Also if the parent and grandchild need to both call the function, what is the best way to handle that? Should/can it be a reference on the parent like:

```
  static get childContextTypes()
  {
    return {
      fn: PropTypes.function,
    };
  }

  getChildContext()
  {
    return {
      openLogin: this._handleOpenLogin,
   };
  }

  function(e) {
    this.setState({
      showLoginDialog: true,
    });
  }
```

Or should the parent reference the context too and have the literal function defined there?

****UPDATE****

This dosen't seem to work...

```
export default class MyParent extends Component {

  static get childContextTypes()
  {
    return {
      myFunc: PropTypes.function,
    };
  }

  getChildContext()
  {
    return {
      myFunc:  myOtherFunc() {
        this.setState({
          someVal: true
        });
      }
    };
  }


...


export default class MyChild extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  contextTypes = {
    myFunc: PropTypes.function.isRequired
  }

  componentWillMount(){
     console.log('willMount');
    _testFn();
    }
  }

  _testFn () {
    this.context.myFunc();
  }

...
```

Returns `cannot read property isRequired of undefined.`

Comment: A second question: will `this.context` be accessible inside the parent by referencing it?

Comment: `this` inside myFunc in MyParent will have global scope. It cannot call `setState()` for MyParent

Comment: So that would imply a parent function could not also be referenced, so how would one go about updating parent state from a grandchild (ideally without having to go though children - which I though was the whole point of context)?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the parent component (where the function was declared) inside the function body, and you notice that the reference to the parent instance was lost when any child calls the function, right?

In your first snippet, you must bind the function to your parent component so it will be the `this` instance when invoked by a child in any level.

```
getChildContext()
{
  return {
    openLogin: this._handleOpenLogin.bind(this),
  };
}
```

The `this` keyword is maybe one of the most tricky things in JavaScript. If you are not very familiar with how it works there, I'd recommend you to dive into some resources a little bit more. Try this one, for example: [Fixing Common Issues](https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-javascripts-this-keyword/).

On the other hand, in your second snippet, you have misspelled the PropType property, thus it is undefined. Take a look at the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#react.proptypes) for the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

You do it in the same way as for strings and bool. The context type should be `PropTypes.func`

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component{
// some funcs
  static childContextTypes = {
    fn: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }
  getChildContext() {
    return { 
        fn : function(arg){
            // do someting with arg
          }
      }
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component{
  contextTypes = {
    fn: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }
  someOtherFunc(){
    this.context.fn(someArg);
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question to clarify how best to handle calling it from both places....

Comment: Additional info added to question... does not seem to work.